# GStreamer pipe to another player

Tags: windows, gstreamer, mplayer

Does anyone know if it's possible to pipe output from the Windows version of GStreamer (using gst-launch) to another player like MPlayer? I think if this were Linux I could use a fdsink or filesink location=/dev/stdout. The Windows version apparently only has filesink and I can't convince the location to be stdout. I've tried - and con as location. The - does nothing. Con won't pipe, but will dump to the console. I also thought fakesink using dump would work, but apparently not.

Alternatively I'd be curious as to whether I can pipe an RTP stream into MPLayer directly. That would eliminate my need to use GStreamer. I know I can make it work with an SDP file pointing to the source address/port, but there is another piece of software I need to run that actually does the retrieval of the RTP packets and I was hoping to just be able to pipe them into MPlayer.

Answer (score -1):

Can you use a named pipe. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe suggests there is no command line interface in Windows and I think I'd need that.

Comment: I've written a program to use named pipes. I know the data is getting into the pipe correctly (I can read from the pipe and forward to a network address and play the video), but reading from the pipe directly into either GStreamer or MPlayer